# pop won't work in my Ruby program?

Tags: ruby

I just don't know why my code stops and don't understand what my terminal is trying to tell me. My code works until `pop` then I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `word' for Ex25:Module
```

This is the code:

```
module Ex25
  def self.break_words(stuff)
    # This function will break up words for us.
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    words
  end

  def self.sort_words(words)
    # Sorts the words.
    words.sort()
  end

  def self.print_first_word(words)
    # Prints the first word and shifts the others down
    word = words.shift()
    puts word
  end

  def self.print_last_word(words)
    # Print the last word after popping it off the end.
    words = words.pop()
    puts word
  end
```

Running this in IRB:

```
irb(main):004:0> sorted_words = Ex25.sort_words(words)
=> ["All", "come", "good", "things", "those", "to", "wait.", "who"]
irb(main):005:0> Ex25.print_first_word(words)
All
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> Ex25.print_last_word(words)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `word' for Ex25:Module
from /Users/lemonsquares/Ruby/ex25.rb:22:in `print_last_word'
from (irb):6
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def self.print_last_word(words)
  # Print the last word after popping it off the end.
  words = words.pop()
  puts word
end
```

should be

```
def self.print_last_word(words)
  # Print the last word after popping it off the end.
  word = words.pop()
  puts word
end
```

You just had a typo I think - look at the difference in the third line.

Comment: I knew it was something trivial like that. sigh Thanks for helping me get my sea legs!

Answer (score 0):

Actually to get the `first` and `last` you have Ruby array methods called `first` and `last'.

Your program could write as

```
  def self.break_words(stuff)
    # This function will break up words for us.
    stuff.split(' ')
  end

  def self.sort_words(words)
    words.sort
  end

  def self.print_first_word(words)
    words.first
  end

  def self.print_last_word(words)
    words.last
  end
```

This is because in Ruby, the last line of the method will automatically return :), and remove the obvious comments.